# Ошибка создания бина Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Помогите разобраться. Создал простое Spring Boot приложение. Хочу чтобы в момент запуска приложения создался объект `MyStr`. Сейчас при запуске появляется ошибка (ниже стектрейс). Насколько понял, у меня нигде не указан `ContextLoaderListener`, который и позволяет создать объекты. Так и не нашел примера, как и куда добавить слушатель `ContextLoaderListener`. Насколько понял можно все решить с помощью аннотаций по типу `@WebListener`, но сколько не пробовал ничего не получается.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(value = "com.example")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    private MyStr str;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "strQ")
    public void setStr(MyStr str) {
        this.str = str;
        String a="";
    }
}
```

Класс для связывания:

```
public class MyStr {
    private String str;

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
}
```

Spring Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>

    <bean id="strQ" class="com.example.MyStr">
        <qualifier value="strQ"/>
        <property name="str" value="Mess"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Ошибка:

```
2016-09-15 10:52:35.195 ERROR 12364 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MyController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setStr' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.MyStr] found for dependency [com.example.MyStr]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.MyStr] found for dependency [com.example.MyStr]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:648) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.MyStr] found for dependency [com.example.MyStr]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, что Spring Boot не читает ваш конфиг в формате XML. Можно попробовать следующее:

- подключить XML конфиг с помощью [`@ImportResourse`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html)
- обьявить ваш бин программно, в классе `DemoApplication`:

Пример:

```
@Bean(name = "strQ")
public MyStr getMyStr() {
    MyStr str = new MyStr();
    str.setStr("Mess");
    return str;
}
```

Comment: спасибо!!! @ImportResourse помог, в чем может быть причина того, что Spring не видит конфигурацию? В Spring Application Context указаны все файлы... При этом в обычном Spring приложении (не Boot) с этим проблемы нет.

Comment: Причина в том, что Spring Boot работает несколько иначе. Кстати, вы можете убрать `<context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>` так как у вас уже есть `@ComponentScan(value = "com.example")` который делает тоже самое.